# SQL Job PowerShell task fails same command succeeds as user

Tags: sql-server-agent, powershell

Simple requirement: delete files on remote path older than 20 days.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ChildItem `
    -Path \\FileServer\SQLBackups\SQLServer\ `
    -File -Recurse -Force | 
  Where-Object {
    ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-20))
} | Remove-Item
```

The above command succeeds (vanity backticks & linebreaks added for readability).

The relevant SQL 2016 Job (backticks and linebreaks not added, but the command text is the same)

```sql
@subsystem=N'PowerShell',
@command=N'Get-ChildItem -Path \\FileServer\SQLBackups\SQLServer\ -File -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-20))}|Remove-Item', 
@proxy_name=N'XPProxy'
```

The error information returned by PowerShell is:

> 'A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.

No permissions issues (refer proxy_name); 
SQL Powershell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision

-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

SQL `@@VERSION`:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Below is the actual parameter list of the [`Get-ChildItem` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-4.0). Why can't SQL use the `-File` parameter?

```
Get-ChildItem 
   [[-Path] <String[]>] 
   [[-Filter] <String>] 
   [-Attributes {ReadOnly | Hidden | System | Directory | Archive | Device | Normal | Temporary | SparseFile | ReparsePoint | Compressed | Offline | NotContentIndexed | Encrypted | IntegrityStream | NoScrubData}] 
   [-Depth <UInt32>] 
   [-Directory] 
   [-Exclude <String[]>] 
   [-File] 
   [-Force] 
   [-Hidden] 
   [-Include <String[]>] 
   [-Name] 
   [-ReadOnly] 
   [-Recurse] 
   [-System] 
   [-UseTransaction] 
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: What are the `[#MediaServerIP#]`/`[#SQLInstanceName#]` tokens/how are they getting replaced with the actual path the command is executing? I'm wondering if the command is getting interrupted with a space or special character (which would mean `Get-ChildItem` executes before ever reading the `-File` flag)

Comment: Hi Peter - UNC values hardcoded in the call on the job removed for simplicity and security. Could be FileServer, SQLServer respectively ;)

Comment: Are you able to minimally reproduce the behavior without those specific values? E.g. create `c:\temp\foo.txt` locally on your sql server and then modify the job to try and delete foo.txt?

Comment: trying DEL \\FileServer\SQLBackups\SQLServer\File.bak. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Invalid Path: '\\FileServer\SQLBackups\SQLServer\File.bak'
SAME command did succeed in Powershell...

Comment: Well _that_ sounds like a permissions issue ;p

Comment: Peter - you are awesome with the work you did on my question; thanks a million. 
I wonder if the UNC path \\ and folder \ characters need to be escaped?.. testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98843/discussion-between-peter-vandivier-and-alocyte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

> cd C:

---

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\FileServer\SQLBackups\SQLServer\ -File -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-20))}|Remove-Item
```

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/powershell-for-network-path
http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2013/05/quick-tip-navigating-to-a-unc-within-sqlps/

Adding the `cd C:` line to my Powershell task in SQL Job allowed UNC references to resolve remote server file directory.

To quote a wise man:
"SQL Server Agent integrates with powershell in very unintuitive ways sometimes"

Thanks for your help, Peter.